# Custom admin url, now some admin modules redirect to frontend

Tags: admin, url, redirect, custom

I have moved the magento admin to a seperate node, thus updated the settings in admin to set admin url as custom : thus admin.example.com, which points to that servers ip.

All ok, but I find a lot of 3rd party modules are no longer working in admin.
If selected from menu, they flip to frontend url, and thus exists admin.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps you had Auto-redirect to Base URL enabled in Web -> URL options?

Comment: Possibly. The requirement to have admin on a separate node was scrapped by the client (don't recall why) so the issue became a NOP.

Comment: ok, I just have this implemented on a project and it works quite ok, except an issue I posted yesterday and thus found your post

Answer (score 5):

Check their config.xml.

I think instead of "extending" the Mage_Adminhtml Controllers, they implement their own. But at this moment, I have no idea, why this is technical a problem - maybe it is not ;-)

## correct

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <my_customer before="Mage_Adminhtml">Namespace_Module_Adminhtml</my_customer>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

## wrong

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <YOUR_NEW_ROUTER_NAME_HERE>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Namespace_Module_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontName>my_module</frontName>
            </args>
        </YOUR_NEW_ROUTER_NAME_HERE>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I did check this, but it is EVERY 3rd party module, not just one or two. Basically what I see is any admin usr that does not include the /admin/, like core modules do. I am thinking the issue here is not related to magento at all, I have used this feature many times in the past. Need to look at rewrites in other places, possible some directive in .htaccess or apache vhost setup.

Comment: Even my own modules (and i know they are done right ;) )

Comment: So the link is to the frontend base uri and not the backend base uri?

Comment: Nope, the link is correct, to admin uri.